# Is there a package to connect R to AWS SSM?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services

Python has an SSM client in the Boto 3 package: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html. Is there something similar for R? If not, any recommendations for how to make something similar? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment a package called [paws on github](https://github.com/paws-r/paws)

> Access over 150 AWS services, including Machine Learning Translation
>   Natural Language Processing Databases File Storage

Or the [cloudyr project](https://cloudyr.github.io/)

> Welcome to the cloudyr project! The goal of this initiative is to make
>   cloud computing with R easier, starting with robust tools for working
>   with cloud computing platforms. The project’s inital work is with
>   Amazon Web Services, various crowdsourcing platforms, and popular
>   continuous integration services for R package development. Tools for
>   Google Cloud Services and Microsoft Azure are also on the long-term
>   agenda.

I only checked paws and that has the ssm functionality according to the [paws documentation about ssm](https://paws-r.github.io/docs/ssm/). The cloudyr project has many aws packages on cran. Not sure if in one of them is the ssm functionality.